# Why does this Perspective Projection Matrix Calculation not give the correct result?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, projection, perspective

I can't quite figure this out.
I've got an OpenGL application I'm converting from the old fixed function pipeline to the programmable pipeline, and getting rid of the deprecated functions I've been using...
I'm not the best when it comes to math, and matrixes are fairly new to me.

However, I've gotten my ModelView matrix working okay, but I can't seem to get the Perspective matrix working right.

By which, I mean, I can use the fixed function deprecated functions, get the value of the matrix, and match it to the calculated values I've generated... ModelView? No problem. Perspective? It doesn't match, and I don't understand why.

The two methods can be toggled between by commenting out the preprocessor #define USEPROJMATRIX

```
typedef float vec_t;

const static vec_t identityMatrix[16] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                                          0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                                          0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

const static vec_t zeroMatrix[16] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

const double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;

float Utils::Radians(const float& degrees)
{
    return degrees * (pi / 180);
}

vec_t* Utils::FrustumMatrix(vec_t* out_matrix, const vec_t& left, const vec_t& right, const vec_t& bottom, const vec_t& top, const vec_t& znear, const vec_t& zfar) // Replaced glFrustum()
{
    memcpy(out_matrix, zeroMatrix, 16*sizeof(vec_t));

    out_matrix[0] = (2.0 * znear) / (right - left);
    out_matrix[5] = (2.0 * znear) / (top - bottom);
    out_matrix[8] = (right + left) / (right - left);
    out_matrix[9] = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    out_matrix[10] = -((zfar + znear) / (zfar - znear));
    out_matrix[11] = -1.0;
    out_matrix[14] = -((2.0 * zfar * znear) / (zfar - znear));

    return out_matrix;
}

vec_t* Utils::PerspectiveMatrix(vec_t* out_matrix, const vec_t& yFOVDegrees, const vec_t& aspectRatio, const vec_t& znear, const vec_t& zfar) // Replaces gluPerspective()
{
    vec_t range, left, right, bottom, top;

    range = tan(Radians(yFOVDegrees / 2)) * znear;
    left = -range * aspectRatio;
    right = range * aspectRatio;
    bottom = -range;
    top = range;

    return FrustumMatrix(out_matrix, left, right, bottom, top, znear, zfar);
}

#define USEPROJMATRIX
void GameLogic::OnResize(int width = 640, int height = 480)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
#ifndef USEPROJMATRIX
    glLoadMatrixf(identityMatrix);
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
#else
    vec_t pMatrix[16];
    memcpy(pMatrix, identityMatrix, sizeof(vec_t) * 16);
    Utils::PerspectiveMatrix(pMatrix, 45.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
    glLoadMatrixf(pMatrix);
#endif

    vec_t projectionmatrix[16];
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projectionmatrix);

    /* Matrix calculation results in projectionmatrix equalling this:
       1.8106601, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 
       0.00000000, 2.4142134, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 
       0.00000000, 0.00000000, -1.0020020, -1.0000000,
       0.00000000, 0.00000000, -2.0020020, 0.0000000
    */
    /* GL calculation
       1.8106601, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000,
       0.00000000, 2.4142137, 0.00000000, 0.00000000,
       0.00000000, 0.00000000, -1.0020020, -1.0000000,
       0.00000000, 0.00000000, -2.0020020, 0.00000000
    */

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadMatrixf(identityMatrix);
}
```

I'm checking my values both by direct observation and by comparing matrix values.
The resultant values are listed in the comments above, and I've no idea why they don't match. The manually calculated matrix visually distorts the rendered scene(a simple cube offset to the lower-left of center) by not positioning it correctly, and I believe it's rendered smaller as well.

*edit*
Fixed the stupid mistake as per Nicol Bolas' answer. This still doesn't work properly, though. Values in the comment have been updated as well.
*edit2*
Code above works fine now, question resolved. Stupid mistakes on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you use in your `gluPerspective` call:

```
(GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height
```

This is what you use in your `Utils::PerspectiveMatrix` call:

```
width / height
```

The first one produces a floating-point value. The second produces an integer. I'm guessing you wanted the first.

Comment: That was a stupid mistake on my part indeed. However, the problem remains. The numbers still aren't matching up. I believe the projectionmatrix[5] element's slight mismatch is just a rounding error or the significant digits of pi in use, but projectionmatrix[15] is completely wrong.

Comment: Annnnd, crap. Found the problem. Was initializing my matrix wrong. Question corrected to correct code, thanks for pointing out the obvious that I was too blind to see. :)